# Cleaning ViewModels MVVM Light and Xamarin forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, cross-platform, mvvm-light, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to clean one view model when i'm leaving back one page as shown in this sketch:

A -> B -> C -> B
when i get back from C->A i want to clean the viewmodel.

I tried to override OnAppearing() and OnDisappearing() from ContentPage, but they called everytime I enter/leave one page. Is it possible to get the navigation direction?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to hook into some of the navigation [events](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/#Public_Events) . Another approach is to do viewmodel -> viewmodel navigation. in each viewmodel you inject a provider to your data e.g. IWizardDataProvider. Then you use this provider to encapsulate a singleton og have it injected as a singleton/singleinstance. When ever you get to the A page, you call a Create() on your provider which can clear the current instance with collected information. The other pages/viewmodels should the use the .Current to add information.